# Is there any point in using keyValuePair to store data in MongoDB, if one can store the key in the objectID?

Tags: mongodb, key-value, objectid

If I have a set of key value pairs, and the keys are unique, is there any advantage in not using the keys as ObjectIDs?

Comment: MongoDB stores data in [documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html) as key-value pairs; the keys are represented as strings and the values can be of varied types (scalar values like an integer or a compound value like an array). The keys in a document are the field names. In general one uses user (or programmer) friendly names for the keys. For example, I would use key names as "userName" or "accountNumber". The keys are not only for identifying a field but also to use them in the queries ( all  the CRUD operations).

Comment: ok but why not rather make an objectId out of your primary key?  Surely this would take up less space and allow you to access the data faster?

Comment: The `_id` field (or key) is mandatory in each document. This has a default and immutable unique value for each document. The value for this field is `ObjectId`, if you don't supply one. And, the `_id` acts as the primary key for a MongoDB collection.

Comment: Yes, so since you can specify the _id field to any value you like, why not always store the key in the _id ?  What possible advantage is there in having an objectID, then a separate different key, and a value.  Why not just have the key in the objectID and the value in the value?

Comment: The `_id` _is_ the key. It can be used in a query, e.g., `db.collection.find( { _id: "some vlaue" } )`, and this _some value_ can be an integer or a string or an ObjectId. I am not sure I am following what you are abstracting - please post, if possible, an example.

Comment: In other words, what is the benefit to store a keyValuePair as a document, where the objectID for this document is the 12 byte autogenerated ID, when one could store your key as the objectID (not the autogenerated 12 byte ID) .  i.e. why would objectID: aabbccddeeff1122  Key: a  Value: b  be better than objectID: a Value: b